# Custom Attribute to a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

what i want to do that when i click a button it opens specific modal like when i click button1 it opens modal1 and so on , how can i achieve this :

HTML :

```
 <div id="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-background">
        <div class="modal-inners">
          <h2>I'm a Modal 11111</h2>
          <p>I am text</p>
          <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-background">
        <div class="modal-inners">
          <h2>I'm a Modal 2222</h2>
          <p>i am text</p>
          <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div id="modal-effect" class="button">One</div>
        <div id="modal-effect" class="button">Two</div>
```

css :

```
#modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: 1;
}
#modal-container.modal-effect {
  transform: scaleY(0.01) scaleX(0);
  animation: unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.modal-effect .modal-background .modal-inners {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: zoomIn 0.5s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.modal-effect.out {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: unfoldOut 1s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.modal-effect.out .modal-background .modal-inners {
  animation: zoomOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal-inners {
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}

#modal-container .modal-background .modal-inners .modal-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


.buttons {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #009bd5;
}

@keyframes unfoldIn {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes unfoldOut {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('#modal-container').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('out');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
});
```

EDIT : Here is the full working modal i want to specify which button and modal is clicked to make it open .

what i want to do i want to add something like **modal-numbers** attribute when i click on a button it opens specific modal popup.

Comment: Can you add the css.

Comment: sorry for late , css added with the full modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, use class instead of ids unless absolutely necessary.  Ids are for identifying individual objects.  If you want a group of objects to have a similar behavior then you use CSS classes.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#container-'+buttonId).removeClass('out').addClass('modal-effect');
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('.modal-container').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('out');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
});
```

```css
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: 1;
}
.modal-effect {
  transform: scaleY(0.01) scaleX(0);
  animation: unfoldIn 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
.modal-effect .modal-background .modal-inners {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: zoomIn 0.5s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
.modal-effect.out {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: unfoldOut 1s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
.modal-effect.out .modal-background .modal-inners {
  animation: zoomOut 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

.modal-effect .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal-effect .modal-background .modal-inners {
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-effect .modal-background .modal-inners .modal-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


.buttons {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #009bd5;
}

@keyframes unfoldIn {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes unfoldOut {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container-modal-one" class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-background">
        <div class="modal-inners">
          <h2>I'm a Modal 11111</h2>
          <p>I am text</p>
          <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container-modal-two" class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-background">
        <div class="modal-inners">
          <h2>I'm a Modal 2222</h2>
          <p>i am text</p>
          <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div id="modal-one" class="button">One</div>
        <div id="modal-two" class="button">Two</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dominique Fortin , can you tell me when to use classes and when to use ID's ? im a bit confused from the solution ^^

Comment: In css, it a bad idea to use the id (sometimes, you have to, because you integrate code from other programmers that you can't change for some reason). The use of css classes in javascript is generally for manipulating a group of DOM object that will have the same behavior. Use css classes with good names and you won't have any problems to do what you want.